# 403 errors on random subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions

I am currently building a small promo website for my company and I am having a very strange error. My current folder structure looks like this currently: `/promo/companies/[company1, company2, company3]/` and I am trying to display a `logo.png` from each of the three company folders on a `companies.php` page in `/promo/`. The image from `company3` displays just fine but for some reason the images in the other two folders are returning 403 errors instead. I have tried putting a `.htaccess` file to allow access to these folders with the contents:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

I have a copy of this file in the `companies` folder as well as each subfolder (`company1`, etc.) but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the file permissions on the files. Usually, you uploaded it and you own it. Apache or WWW is the user for the web server and it doesn't have access to them. So, you have to give "other' access or change the owner to the web server.

Comment: Also check the error logs for a more specific detail

Comment: Gosh I feel stupid, all this time mucking around with the .htaccess files and I didn't even think to check the permissions! Glad it wasn't something worse